# Understanding Wigner’s friend scenario

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

I recently watched this video https://youtu.be/Wsjgtp9XZxo?si=sIRlAbvAm2wjXRNP
and tried (unsuccessfully, because i don’t have the knowledge required) to read Bruckner’s paper.
What i am missing, is the reason why  Hossenfelder is saying that we need a big enough apparatus to cause decoherence in order to make a measurement. Why an interaction between photons is NOT a measurement? What are her proof that reality exist?
Also, i read Rovelli’s book about relational quantum mechanics and it seemed to me that he didn’t exclude an underlying objective reality, instead he says that there is only a subjective knowable reality.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why Hossenfelder specifically sez about decoherence and measurement. However, a measurement has to produce a record of what was measured that can be copied. A measurement result isn't much use if people can't read about it and discuss it so it has to be possible to make multiple copies of the measurement result.

When information about a measurement result is copied this prevents quantum interference between different possible measurement values: this is called decoherence:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

So copying is required for measurement results and copying prevents interference.

Comment: So i still can’t see why the Bruckner’s experiment is not a measurement. They said they recorded the results in a memory, so this interaction IS a measurement.